# Wait for response from Async , Protractor, nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, asynchronous, protractor

I am trying to create a helper function that makes an async call which is a part of my data setup for the protactor test. is there a way i can wait for the response of the function and then proceed with the tests, here is what I am trying to do.

so basically the test should wait until the async call lo loaddata() is finished. I have read about use of promises but couldn't get to implement it sucessfully.

```
"use strict";

describe('sample passing test spec', function() {
describe('sample passing test suite', function() {
  loaddata();
    it('sample passing test', function () {
    datall();
        expect("1").toEqual("2");
    });
    });
});



loaddata() is basically making a socket connection 

function loaddata(){
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(20000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
console.log('Connected');
client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client\n');
});


client.on('data', function(data) {
console.log('Received: ' + data);
client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});

client.on('close', function() {
console.log('Connection closed');
});

return "function execution over"

}
```

Comment: In Javascript, you cannot "wait" for an async operation to be done.  You can either schedule a callback to be called or return a Promise that will trigger it's `.then()` handler when the event is done.  Other code will continue to run while the async operation is doing its thing.  You can't wait in Javascript.  Probably worth reading this [How do I return a response from an asynchronous operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to tweak `loaddata` to *return a promise* which would Protractor put on the [Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) - a queue of pending promises to resolve:

```
function loaddata() {
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
    var net = require('net');

    var client = new net.Socket();
    client.connect(20000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
        console.log('Connected');
        client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client\n');
    });


    client.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Received: ' + data);
        client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
        deferred.fulfill(true);
    });

    client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

---

If this is something you need to do globally before your test run, put it into `onPrepare()` and return. If `loaddata` returns a promise, `Protractor` would first resolve it and only then run tests:

```
onPrepare: function () { 
    return loaddata();
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.